# what is the READ_COMMITTED locking strategy when concurrently operating with a READ_UNCOMMITTED transaction

Tags: informix, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

We have two transactions, one READ_COMMITTED and the other READ_UNCOMMITTED. We face a lock exception in the READ_COMMITTED transaction. This exception happens when the other READ_UNCOMMITTED transaction modifies the record the READ_COMMITTED is trying to retrieve. My READ_UNCOMMITTED transaction takes a bit more time to complete. As per the isolation strategy, READ_UNCOMMITTED doesn't acquire locks, READ_COMMITTED does.

My question is

1. what locking strategy does READ_COMMITTED follow here.
2. Will it acquire lock on that non-committed record from READ_UNCOMMITTED transaction? or on the committed record from previous transactions.

Comment: We use informix

Comment: I need a bit more information to understand your question. What version of `Informix` are you using? Can you provide a simple example with a dummy table of what your 2 transactions are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The session that has readcommitted transaction will have shared lock for a very short time span, as soon as sql server finishes reading, this shared lock is released. If another session with read uncommitted transaction is trying to update the same record at the same time it will be blocked for a very small interval of time till the shared lock is not released.

Read uncommitted transaction reads dirty records that is uncommitted records and does not issue shared locks. But the transaction will still issue exclusive locks.